# How can I add responsive image support on my website using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using twitter bootstrap. I am targeting my website for mobile and tab users only.I want images to resize according to different screen sizes. I tried using Adaptive responsive images http://adaptive-images.com/ but its way to complex. Please suggest me best alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this post, it explain about optimizing images for responsive display and avoiding multiple image download
 http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/10/how-to-avoid-duplicate-downloads-in-responsive-images/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make images responsive in Bootstrap is with simple CSS..

```
img {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://bootply.com/60914)

If you concerned about image quality / high-res, I'd recommend taking a look at [**Responsive Images**](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/responsive-images/) which is a JS solution to load different resolution images (once) based on screen size.